# How to remove single quote and put double quotes in the array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, double-quotes, single-quotes

I want to remove single quotes and put double quotes in the array of objects in javascript.

```
var arr=[{ email: 'abc@gmail.com', name: 'Abc' },
         { email: 'def@hotmail.com', name: 'Dr.Def' },
         { email: 'xyz@gmail.com', name: 'Xyz' },
         { email: 'cad@hotmail.com', name: 'Cad' }];
```

**I want output be like:**

```
var arr=[{"email":"abc@gmail.com","name":"Abc"},
         {"email":"def@hotmail.com","name":"Dr.Def"},
         {"email":"xyz@gmail.com","name":"Xyz"},
         {"email":"cad@hotmail.com","name":"Cad"}];
```

Comment: Double quote is the standard when you use `JSON.stringify`. If you're not happy with it, just use `replace`.

Comment: `var teachers = JSON.stringify(arr)`

Comment: Youve just asked here and the answer is correct https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552242/how-to-remove-single-quote-from-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: Wat? What you have there is a Javascript array/object literal. Single and double quotes are exactly equivalent in it. It doesn't matter which one it is. Why do you care? If you want to convert this Javascript array to JSON, in its entirety, then the JSON encoder will use double quotes for strings properly, since that's relevant to JSON.

Comment: @KhyatiSharma for what purpose you are doing so ? what it does after double-quotes. Try using `JSON.stringify(arr)`  `stringify` is made for you .

Comment: `JSON.stringify(arr)` returns a JSON **string** not an array. It's unclear what you're asking but you might want to read this [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 1):

Just stringify the whole array?

```js
var arr=[{ email: 'abc@gmail.com', name: 'Abc' },
         { email: 'def@hotmail.com', name: 'Dr.Def' },
         { email: 'xyz@gmail.com', name: 'Xyz' },
         { email: 'cad@hotmail.com', name: 'Cad' }];
         
 console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
```

If you want the `var arr =` too just prepend it on `console.log('var arr = ' + JSON.stringify(arr))`.